# Adding something under what's new section of Android app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have published my first Android app on Google play and submitted an updated new APK with few bug fixes and new features recently. In Google play listing, it shows that the application was updated on 11 April 2013. I want to add some text under 'What's new' tab so that my users know what is new in the updated version. I just can't find the right place to put in the text.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This assumes you're using the newish console since the old one will be retired April 15th)

It's now called "Recent Changes" under Store Listing on the left. Scroll down a little bit and you'll see it.